# Curl output to CSV-BASH

Tags: json, bash, csv, curl

with this command i get JSON output:

```
curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "http://192.168.253.21:4440/api/20/project/test/executions?authtoken=kH44NoX35bp1zxohgkMtsOIC9H9tw6UI" | jq -r '.|[.executions[] | select(.job.name != null) | select(.job.name|contains("JIRA_Create_Subtask")) ] | sort_by(.id) | reverse | .[0] | [.status, .job.name, ."date-started".date, ."date-ended".date, .job.project]' > /tmp/1.txt

cat /tmp/1.txt
[
  "succeeded",
  "JIRA_Create_Subtask",
  "2018-04-16T10:00:00Z",
  "2018-04-16T10:00:02Z",
  "test"
]
```

How to get this output in csv format:

```
"succeeded","JIRA_Create_Subtask","2018-04-16T10:00:00Z","2018-04-16T10:00:02Z","test"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can use `@csv` format in `jq`:](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions)

```
curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "http://192.168.253.21:4440/api/20/project/test/executions?authtoken=kH44NoX35bp1zxohgkMtsOIC9H9tw6UI" |
jq -r '.|[.executions[] |
   select(.job.name != null) |
   select(.job.name|contains("JIRA_Create_Subtask")) ] |
   sort_by(.id) | reverse | .[0] |
   [.status, .job.name, ."date-started".date, ."date-ended".date, .job.project] |
   @csv'
```

Comment: getting jq: command not found error.

Comment: You need to install `jq` on your system.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any space or square brackets in your values, you can use `tr`:

```
cat 1.txt | tr -d '[]\n '
```

`tr` deletes any `[`, `]`, cariage return or space characters.